# custom jQuery slideshow interval questions

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm building a custom jQuery slideshow as a way of learning the language. So far, it auto-advances, and has previous/next buttons.

1. After clicking next, how can I disable the next button until the animation is completed? (multiple fast clicks messes things up)
2. After clicking next, can the interval be reset so it's another 3000 ms until the next auto advance?

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7u6BL/1/)

ps- Sorry if the code is ugly, hopefully the adorable puppy pictures makes up for it. :)

Comment: I have added solution without reading your code, now its fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#next').click(function(){
   var m = this;
     $(m).attr('disabled', 'true');
    $('.bslide img:last-child')
         .fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('.bslide img:last-child')
           .prependTo($('.bslide'));
    $('.bslide img:last-child')
         .prev().show();
     $(m).attr('disabled', 'false');
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**buttons**

you don't have to disable them, better you simply reset your animations before you use fade / show - i.e. instead of

```
$('.bslide img:last-child').fadeOut(1000, ...
```

use

```
$('.bslide img:last-child').stop().fadeOut(1000, ...
```

**interval**

you can store a handle to your interval using `var my_iv = setInterval(...)` and each time the user click 'next' you simple cancel it with `clearInterval(my_iv)` and restart it

also your interval does not need duplicated code, a simple `$('#next').click()` should be enough...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using .stop() almost works, except that it stops the fadeout, so when that picture comes back around, it's at whatever opacity it stopped at.